Matryoshka doll problem
Notation: We fix some integer $d \geq 1$ and $N \geq 2$. We use $[m, n]$ to denote the set of integers $\{m, \dots, n\}$, and $\mathbb L_N := [1, N]^d$ to denote the set $\{1, \dots, N\}^d \subset \mathbb Z^d$.
At each point $x := (x_1, \dots, x_d) \in \mathbb L_N$ is a Matryoshka doll, represented by the subset $\{x\} \subset \mathbb L_N$. In general, a Matryoshka doll is defined to be any subrectangle $\prod_{i = 1}^N [m_i, n_i]$ of $\mathbb L_N$.
A collection $\mathcal M$ of Matryoshka dolls is said to be a valid configuration if given any two distinct elements of $\mathcal M$, either they are disjoint or one is a proper subset of the other.
Question: What valid configuration of Matryoshka dolls in $\mathbb L_N$ achieves the maximal cardinality $|\mathcal M|$? Is it unique, possibly up to some symmetry?

I feel this problem may be quite difficult due to the recurrence inherent in the set up…

What bounds on cardinality have you found? For $d=1$ the answer would seem to be $2N-1$ by building a binary tree on subintervals, and I feel like a similar construction should work in the higher-$d$ case; e.g., by alternating dimensions we get ${{[i]\times[j]: 1\leq i,j\leq N}$ $\cup{[2i, 2i+1]\times[j]: 1\leq (2i), j\leq N}$ $\cup{[2i, 2i+1]\times[2j, 2j+1]}: 1\leq(2i), (2j)\leq N}$ $\cup\ldots}$. (Note that for non-power-of-two $N$ you have to intersect these intervals with $[1,N]$ to keep from spilling over but that shouldn't affect things too much.)

@StevenStadnicki Yes, I have more or less verified $2N - 1$ for $d = 1, N = 2^k$. For higher values of $d$, or other values of $N$, it seems like number theoretic properties may come into play.

Can you give a specific example? e.g., Taking $d=2, N=5$ can one beat the construction above? (There's almost certainly a nice Pigeonhole Principle proof for $2N-1$ in the $d=1$ case, but I'd have to think.)

@StevenStadnicki I am not sure if I understand your construction tbh, the notation is a bit hard to parse. If there's an easy, verbal description of the construction process I think that would help. Otherwise you might have to describe it mathematically in an answer below.

Think about it this way: start with your initial grid and choose one of the dimensions. 'Reduce by two' along this dimension: pair each $\langle 2i, j, k, \ldots\rangle$ with $\langle 2i+1, j, k, \ldots\rangle$ to get a collection of $(\frac N2\times N^{d-1})$ $2\times1\times\ldots\times1$ rectangles and now treat these rectangles as your new points. Pair them up along a different dimension to get $(\frac N2\times\frac N2\times N^{d-2})$ $1\times2\times1\ldots\times1$ rectangles of these new points (which is to say, that many $2\times2\times1\ldots$ rectangles of the original points); repeat.

Please do not call $\lbrace 1,\ldots,N \rbrace^d$ a lattice. A (Euclidean) lattice is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z^d$ (or more generally a discrete subgroup of an Euclidean vector space).

I don't understand "the set ${1, \dots, N} \subset \mathbb Z^d$". How is the term on the left a subset of the term on the right?

@GerryMyerson Was a typo, should be ${1, \dots, N}^d$, sorry.

The answer is $2N^d-1$. Just forget about the whole geometry of the problem, even then you cannot get better than $2x-1$ if there is a laminar family of sets on $x$ elements. Obviously, you want to take the whole set. Then pick one maximal set from the remaining ones. You can also assume that its complement is a set, and there is your induction.

Oh nice, how does one show the upper bound of $2x-1$ for any laminar family of sets?

That is the proof that I have sketched in my answer. Which part would you like me to elaborate further?

Oh, thats the proof of the upper bound for the laminar family, not the proof of that $2N^d - 1$ is achieved. To show the latter, its enough to consider the construction by Steven Stadnicki right? Or at least something close in spirit.

Yes, that is the proof for the upper bound, though you can also easily obtain from it a matching lower bound construction.
